# Mail from function dispalying as unknown sender?

Tags: php, html, email-validation

I am trying to display the name from the input field on a contact form to show the name that was entered after the email was submitted, I have changed headers in php and it has changed from cgi-mailer to unbknown sender? How do i get it to display the name of the person whosent the email from the contact form?

Thanks

form process php that controls validtion etc

```
    // define variables and set to empty values
    $name_error = $email_error = "";
    $name = $email = $message = $success = "";
    $from = $_POST['name1'];

    //form is submitted with POST method
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
        if (empty($_POST["name1"])) {
            $name_error = "Name is required";
        } else {
            $name = test_input($_POST["name1"]);
            // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
            if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) {
                $name_error = "Only letters and white space allowed";
            }
        }

        if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
            $email_error = "Email is required";
        } else {
            $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
            // check if e-mail address is well-formed
            if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
                $email_error = "Invalid email format";
            }
        }

        if (empty($_POST["message"])) {
            $message = "";
        } else {
            $message = test_input($_POST["message"]);
        }

        if ($name_error == '' and $email_error == '' ){
            $message_body = '';
            unset($_POST['submit']);
            foreach ($_POST as $key => $value){
                $message_body .=  "$key: $value\n";
            }

            $to = 'devonfoodmovement@gmail.com';
            $subject = 'Contact Form Submit';
            $headers = "From:" . $from;
            if (mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)){
                $success = "Message sent";
                $name = $email = $message = '';
            }
        }

        /*if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
            $from = $_POST['name1'];

            $headers = "From:" . $from;

        }*/

    }

    function test_input($data) {
        $data = trim($data);
        $data = stripslashes($data);
        $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
        return $data;
    }
```

Conotact form html

```
 <?php include('form_process.php');
        /*if (isset($_POST['contact-submit'])){

            $url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify';
            $privatekey = "secretkeygoogle";

            $response = file_get_contents($url."?secret=".$privatekey."&response=".$_POST['g-recaptcha-response']."&remoteip=".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADOR']);

            $data = json_decode($response);

            if(isset($data->success) AND $data->success==true) {

            }else{

            }


        }*/


    ?>
    <div class="home-btn"><a href="http://testsiteclash.co.uk/"><i class="fas fa-home"></i></a></div>
    <div class='grey'>
        <div class="container-contact">
            <form id="contact" method="post">
                <div id="column-contact-left">
                <div class='contact-logo'></div>
                <h3>Contact the Devon Food Movement</h3>
                <fieldset>
                    <input placeholder="Your name" type="text" tabindex="1" name="name1" value="<?= $name ?>" autofocus>

                </fieldset>
                <span class="error"><?= $name_error ?></span>
                <fieldset>
                    <input placeholder="Your Email Address" type="text" name="email" value="<?= $email ?>" tabindex="2" >

                </fieldset>
                <span class="error"><?= $email_error ?></span>
                </div>
                <div id="column-contact-right">
                <fieldset>
                    <textarea placeholder="Type your Message Here...." name="message" value="<?= $message ?>" tabindex="3" ></textarea>
                </fieldset>
                <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="needtoinput" ></div>
                <span class="success"><?= $success; ?></span>
                <fieldset>
                    <button name="submit" type="submit" id="contact-submit" data-submit="...Sending">Submit</button>
                </fieldset>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

New form p[rocess php with seperate mail function

```
    <?php


    // define variables and set to empty values
    $name_error = $email_error = "";
    $name = $email = $message = $success = "";

    //form is submitted with POST method
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
        if (empty($_POST["name1"])) {
            $name_error = "Name is required";
        } else {
            $name = test_input($_POST["name1"]);
            // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
            if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) {
                $name_error = "Only letters and white space allowed";
            }
        }

        if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
            $email_error = "Email is required";
        } else {
            $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
            // check if e-mail address is well-formed
            if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
                $email_error = "Invalid email format";
            }
        }

        if (empty($_POST["message"])) {
            $message = "";
        } else {
            $message = test_input($_POST["message"]);
        }

        if ($name_error == '' and $email_error == '' ){
            $message_body = '';
            unset($_POST['submit']);
            foreach ($_POST as $key => $value){
                $message_body .=  "$key: $value\n";
            }

            $to = 'devonfoodmovement@gmail.com';
            $subject = 'Contact Form Submit';
            if (mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)){
                $success = "Message sent";
                $name = $email = $message = '';
            }
        }

        /*if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
            $from = $_POST['name1'];

            $headers = "From:" . $from;

        }*/

    }

    $from = $_POST['name1'];
    $headers = "From:" . $from;

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    mail($headers);

    }

    function test_input($data) {
        $data = trim($data);
        $data = stripslashes($data);
        $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
        return $data;
    }
```

LATEST PHP for the last comment i made

```
   if ($name_error == '' and $email_error == '' ){
        $message_body = '';
        unset($_POST['submit']);
        foreach ($_POST as $key => $value){
            $message_body .=  "$key: $value\n";
        }



        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $to = 'devonfoodmovement@gmail.com';
        $subject = 'Contact Form Submit';
        $headers = 'From:' . $email . "\n" . 'Reply-to: ' . $email . "\n"  ;
        if (mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)){
            $success = "Message sent";
            $name = $email = $message = '';
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try to make a mail function instead of calling it as is, then return the name and display it wherever you need from the var who called mail function. No need to set void value on vars as they'll be marked as rewritable after the function behavior.

Comment: @JoelBonetR I have changed the form process php file and it is now returning cgi mailer in my email inbox now? I made a seperate mail function

Comment: First of all, you need to specify a valid email address for `From`. Your form field `name1` asks the user to input their name only, that is not a valid email address. Secondly: **Don’t even try this.** It will increase the probability of your mails being classified as spam immensely (because your server is not registered as one that is “allowed” to send emails for the domain the user’s email belongs to) - _send_ the mail using one of your email addresses, that the server is allowed to send for; put the user’s email address in the `Reply-To` field, so that the receiver can easily answer them.

Comment: Take care to the @CBroe advices. I think you're trying to "re-invent the wheel". Use php mail function as it's expected to work, if you want to show a "Thanks, Joe for sending your message" or something similar do what i told you and capture the name, but not modifying default behavior of mailing functionallity, it can be a trully headache and you're in a large quest for something simple...

Comment: it is currently setting my personal email address as the from in my email client as i have the variable $email for the From:

Answer (score 0):

You must have the required fields on your form, then if you want, ask for the name too.

```
   <?php
   function defaultMailing($to, $subject, $txt, $headers){
             if(mail($to, $subject, $txt, $headers)) return true; else return false;
    }
        ?>
```

on the other part (where your form action):

```
$to = $_POST['to'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$txt = $_POST['message'];
//you don't need name, but if you asked for on the form:
$msg = "thanks, ".$_POST['name']." for your message, your request will be answered soon.";

//call to mail function and send the required (to, subject and text/html message) and the optional headers if you want
defaultMailing($to, $subject, $txt, $headers);

//do whatever you want with $msg or with $_POST['name'];
```

If you want to insert the posted name on the message, simply modify $txt var setting the $_POST['name'] wherever you want and then, proceed with defaultMailing call, for example:

```
$to = $_POST['to'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$txt = $_POST['message'];

$name = $_POST['name'];    
$mailMessage = $name.' '.$txt;
//call to mail function and send the required (to, subject and text/html message) and the optional headers if you want
defaultMailing($to, $subject, $mailMessage, $headers);
```

Comment: I am not trying to respond to the person who emails though just display their name in my email client and have the reply to function set to easily reply to whoever contacts me? This appears to be sending a response after receiving an email?

Comment: for making an easy way to response you must use the Reply-To field, the name is optional, you can show it but not use it as a "key" or "id" in any case. You can relation a mail address to an user-name used before, but you may need to store it wherever (as if not you'll have to iterate through all mail files every time and it could be slow as fck in some days). I dont know if we are understanding well what you want, and i'm not sure if you taked pen and paper and think it logicaly... :(

Comment: ah okay so essentially the reguired field in my form for the name is used for validation but i would use reply to to display the senders email address as well making it possibly to reply with an email to the user who sent the enquiry? so trying to display the name entered in the form in my email client as the from in bold is essentially pointless?

Comment: is it because my variable for name is set at the top to an empty string the reason it would return unknown sender when the from is configured?

Comment: right i have got it all working now apart from it is returning unknown sender as the from as i think it is staking the top variable for $name as an empty string. I solved the other problems by using "\n" to seperate the information

Comment: i'm not figuring how are you doing with all of this, at this point i only can say that you must use php standard logic and functions or use a tested library to deal with it, it's not that difficult to make what you're trying to do, but take care at the things that @CBroe told you on a comment. Use var_dump($varname) to debug and enable debug globals on php if needed. I can recommend you to use method attribute inside the form and set it as <? echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?> if you need, instead of this behaviour you posted.

Comment: have added the new bits of php to show what is producing in the email client the inputted email as its from, what i want instead o the email being displayed as the sender i want the name inputted in the form, it is up on my testsite on the contact link http://testsiteclash.co.uk/contact basically i want what the user inputs in the your name input field to be the from in my email client

Comment: do it from scratch, it's a simple php function, you're no aplying the concepts properly and you're arguing with the people that post an answer to your non-problem, simply follow the official php webpage instructions and/or read some commented mailing scripts that you can find on google and you'll understand in 5 minutes what are your faults on your code.

Comment: ? where am i arguing? I have merely asked questions and tried to explain what I am trying to achieve. I have re-written the whole thing and have got it working, why wait 4 days to write a snide comment? Have yourself a lovely day

Comment: cuz i was working out of the office. If you have it working then answer yourself the question and mark it as solved instead of letting it open...

Answer (score 0):

Settles for the email being the from sender as it appears that a from value has to be a valid email address

```
            if ($name_error == '' and $email_error == '' and ($res['success']) ){
            $message_body = '';
            unset($_POST['submit']);

            foreach ($_POST as $key => $value){
                $message_body .=  "$key: $value\n";
            }

            $email = $_POST['email'];
            $to = 'devonfoodmovement@gmail.com';
            $subject = 'Contact Form Submit';
            $headers = 'From:' . $email . "\n" . 'Reply-to: ' . $email . "\n"  ;
            if (mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
                $sent = "Message sent";
                $name = $email = $message = '';
            }
```